# Как в Python прочитать последний символ строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Код на Python,  который читает из одного файла числа, умножает их и записывает в другой файл.
Нужно, чтобы вместо всей строки читался последний символ.

Код:

```py
f = open('a.txt')
m, p = map(int, f.readline().split())
f.close()
f = open('b.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(m*p))
f.close()
```

Содержимое файла a.txt:

15268 14785

Comment: вам надо чтобы из ```a.txt``` читалось только 5?

Comment: Нет, 5 и 8, чтобы результат в файле b.txt был 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немножко ваш код поменял, но теперь оно работает так как вы хотели:

```py
def func(line):
    return int(line[-1])


f = open('a.txt')

m, p = map(func, f.readline().split())

f = open('b.txt', 'w')

f.write(str(m * p))

f.close()
```

Совет от @CrazyElf в действии:

```py
f = open('a.txt')

m, p = map(lambda line: int(line[-1]), f.readline().split())

f = open('b.txt', 'w')

f.write(str(m * p))

f.close()
```

Comment: Для таких коротеньких функций можно использовать `lambda`, чтобы писать их прямо в месте использования.

Comment: Спасибо вам, код работает